# What is the right time when linux suffer drift time?

Tags: linux, kernel, time, uptime

Supose that a linux server, at startup, report the following btime:

boot btime -> 1493875000

This server is virtualized inside a busy box and the I/O load is high, in spite of have ntp running, a month ago the report change:

last btime -> 1493875100

The system suffer a drift of "100" seconds. If the uptime is "2592000" seconds, what is the right btime? what of the following options is the right time?

```
1. boot btime + uptime
   1493875000 + 2592000 = 1496467000

2. boot btime + uptime + drift
   1493875000 + 2592000 + 100 = 1496467100

3. boot btime + uptime - drift
   1493875000 + 2592000 - 100 = 1496466900

4. last btime + uptime
   1493875100 + 2592000 = 1496467100

5. last btime + uptime + drift
   1493875100 + 2592000 + 100 = 1496467200

6. last btime + uptime - drift
   1493875100 + 2592000 - 100 = 1496467000
```

Comment: Where is `btime` coming from?

Comment: Form /proc/stat

Comment: because `boot btime` + `drift` = `last btime`, i would assume options 2 or 4 properly give the answer to the question *"when did this system shut down?"*, at least relative to that VM's concept of time.  there's no guarantee that 1s in that VM is anything like 1s as measured by an [external source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock).